# Mots avec une séquence de voyelles identiques

Tags: vocabulaire, orthographe

**Agréée, créée** possèdent tous les deux une séquence de trois voyelles (quasiment) identiques (hormis l'accent).

Y a-t-il d'autres mots comme ceux-ci ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

il y a aussi

> gréée

et

> suppléée

il y en a peut être d'autres

Comment: Il y a aussi *énucléée* (un mot qu'on utilise tous les jours...)